# Flexicore ceiling electrical install

Tags: wiring

I live in a condo with flexicore ceilings. I would like to install another light fixture in my family room. Can I cut into the core of the flexicore and install greenfield or BX in the channel to the location of the new ceiling fixture?

Comment: I take it by "Flexicore" you are talking about hollow-core precast concrete panel systems?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this? .... `cut into the core of the flexicore`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can answer your question; please edit the info into your question.